# How to display indented yaml in browser with VueJs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, user-interface, yaml

I have an API that takes a JSON object and transforms it into YAML

```
let file = stringify({...yamlTemplate});
res.set('content-type', 'text/plain ');
res.status(200).send(file);
```

When I see the response in the browser console, the YAML has the correct indentation

```
name: test
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize
    paths:
      - force-app/**
jobs:
```

In the frontend, I'm using VueJs. Doing a `console.log` also prints the YAML with the correct indentation.

However, I want to print the yaml to the screen as follows

```
{{yamlResponse}}
```

When I do that, the yaml is displayed as a huge one liner, which breaks all the indentation

```
name: test on: pull_request: types: - opened - synchronize paths: - force-app/** j. 
obs: test: runs-on: ubuntu-latest if:
```

In the end, I want the user to be able to copy the file from the browser, and paste it into their favorite code editor, while keeping the indentation.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using the  tag

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre

This shows the response with the original indentation and can be copied by the user